# Proving that the images of 2 solutions for a system of first order linear homogeneous ODE's are either identical or don't intersect.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $\ \bar y(t), \bar x(t) $ are solutions for the first order linear ODE system $\ \bar x'(t) = A\bar x(t)$ for any $\ t \in \mathbb R$. Show that the only two options for the images of $\ x(t), y(t) $ are either:

1. $\ Im(\bar x) = Im(\bar y) $
2. $\ Im(\bar x) \cap Im(\bar y) = \emptyset $

My thought process is to assume that the images do intersect, and to try and refute my assumption. this is what I've got so far:

$$\ assuming:  Im(\bar x) \cap Im(\bar y) \ne \emptyset \\ \Rightarrow \exists t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb R \ : \ \bar x(t_1) = \bar y(t_2) = P,\ (P \in \mathbb R^n)   $$

Since the general solution for first order linear homogeneous systems of ODE's  is $$\ \bar x(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\bar v_ie^{r_it}$$
Than: $$\ \bar x(t_1) - \bar y(t_2) = 0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i\bar v_ie^{r_it_1})-\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i\bar v_ie^{r_it_2}) \\ \iff a_ie^{t_1}-b_ie^{t_2} = 0 \iff a_i = e^{t_1-t_2}b_i \\ \implies \bar x(t) = e^{t_1-t_2}\bar y(t) $$

Which means that $\ \bar x(t), \bar y(t) $ are linear dependent. However I can't find a way to continue this proof  and deduce 1 and 2.

Any ideas? I'm totally stuck on this one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: careful, you're missing the $r_i$ in your last expressions. To answer your question : examine $x (t - (t_2-t_1))$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: The decomposition is also only true when the eigenvalues are distinct (or at least when the matrix is diagonalizable). The more general case should consider the case where $A$ is not diagonalizable.